# Putting A Box Round A Text Run - For Powerpoint

Tags: powerpoint, openxml, python-pptx

I would like to put a box around a text run in Powerpoint. Specifically a border. For example, a word might have a light green background (done by highlighting) and a thin black border line.

I've solved the "highlighting with a light green background" part - using a RGB value. That's fine.

Is it feasible to draw a box **boundary line** round a run?

I'm specifically looking for an example XML fragment - if this is feasible. (I use python-pptx and augment it with my own XML confection.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe so Martin. A run is not a shape, so it doesn't have a border that can be turned on or off or given a color. You can find an excerpt of the XML schema showing what elements and attributes can go in a run-properties element (`<w:rPr>`) here: https://python-pptx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/dev/analysis/txt-font-underline.html?highlight=CT_TextCharacterProperties#related-schema-definitions

It can have a `ln` child element, which corresponds to a `pptx.dml.line.LineFormat` object, but that's going to set the format of the font "outline", like if you want the interior of each letter to be a different color than its outline. You could create a `LineFormat` object for a run if you wanted to experiment with it using `line = LineFormat(run.font._element)`.

The other test would be whether you can do such a thing from the PowerPoint application UI. If you can't do it on Windows PowerPoint, it's very unusual that you can do it from the XML (although there are a few cases). Mac PowerPoint can't do everything Windows PowerPoint can, so that's less of a compelling "proof".

Comment: I second scanny's comment. You can add a run to a shape, you can't add a shape to a run.

Comment: That was what my research said also. Thanks @scanny and John Korchok.

I thought I'd ask in case I was missing a trick.